# Changing cursor to pointer on Chart.js bar chart when hover (mousemove) event is disabled?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

We are using Chart.js (version 2.6.0) for a bar chart in an Angular 5 application and the client wanted us to disable hover events for chart interactions(they only wanted the bar to change and the tooltips to show up when the user clicked on a bar).

in the bar chart options object, we have the following defined for the events property:

```
events: ["touchstart","touchmove","click"]
```

That disables hovering events over the bar chart. Now however, the client wants us to change the cursor to a pointer when the user hovers over one of the bars, so that they know they can click on it, which is a valid point. I've found several solutions here on SO, but I can't seem to find a way to do it without adding "mousemove" to the events property, which just enables hovering interactions on the entire chart.

What really confuses me is that options.hover has an event property called "onHover" that has a callback, but it fires when ANY of the defined events happens, including clicks.

http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/events.html

Is this even possible without re-enabling the hover interaction in general? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 19):

With Chart.js **3.x**:

```js
onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
    event.native.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
}
```

With Chart.js **2.x**:

```js
onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
    event.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Based on @Luca Fagioli answer, in my case, I didn't want to disable the click events in my chart so i added:

```
events: ['mousemove', 'click'],
onHover: (event, chartElement) => {
  event.target.style.cursor = chartElement[0] ? 'pointer' : 'default';
}
```

now that you have a cursor on the chart you want the cursor in the legend too - if they are clickable - so in the legend settings toy hold add:

```
 onHover: (event) => {
    event.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

For versions > 3.x
you find the **target** under **native**

```
options: {
  plugins : {
    legend: {   
      labels: {
        onHover: function (e) {
          e.native.target.style.cursor = 'pointer';
        },
        onLeave: function (e) {
          e.native.target.style.cursor = 'default';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is almost 5 years old question, using the version 3.x.x of [ChartJS](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/3.9.1/) we just need to declare some event handlers like `onHover`, `onClick` and define the events handle by the `tooltip` like `events: ['click']`.

Here we have a working snippet:

```js
const isArray = a => a instanceof Array
const isNull = a => a == null
const cursor = a => {
  if (isNull(a)) return 'default'
  if (!isArray(a)) return 'pointer'
  if (isArray(a) && a.length > 0) return 'pointer'

  return 'default'
}

const $canvas = document.getElementById('chart')
const onHover = (e, item) => {
  $canvas.style.cursor = cursor(item)
}
const onLeave = () => {
  $canvas.style.cursor = 'default'
}

const onClick = (event, items) => {
  if (items.length === 0) return

  console.log('onclick')
}

const lineChart = new Chart($canvas, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: ['May', 'June', 'July'],
    datasets: [{
      data: [15, 25, 15],
      label: "My Dataset1",
      backgroundColor: "#00F",
      fill: false
    }, {
      data: [35, 15, 25],
      label: "My Dataset2",
      backgroundColor: "#F00",
      fill: false
    }]
  },
  options: {
    responsive: true,
    onHover,
    onClick,
    plugins: {
      tooltip: {
        // Tooltip will only receive click events
        events: ['click'],
      },
      legend: {
        onHover,
        onLeave,
      },
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.9.1/chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="600" height="180"></canvas>
```